# Error when using apply in a function which is working

Tags: r, function, loops, apply

I am trying to use my function using `apply`without success. The `df` exemplify one `row`of my real data-frame.

```
   df <- 'Probe.Set.ID GT1000.CEL GT1001.CEL GT1002.CEL GT1003.CEL GT1004.CEL GT1005.CEL GT1006.CEL GT1007.CEL GT1008.CEL
    AX-100108664  0.8421723  0.9085748  0.9175095  0.9152894 0.9308451 0.09649999 0.06152165  0.1217587  0.9176847'

df <- read.table(text=df, header=T)
```

Using my function it seems to works without any problems:

```
myfunction <- function(thetaR){
  numc <- ncol(thetaR)/2
  theta1 <- thetaR[,1:numc] 
  R <- thetaR[,(numc+1):length(thetaR)]
  interp <- approx(theta1[2:length(theta1)], R[2:length(R)], n =1500)
  res <- numeric(length(theta1))
for(i in 2:length(theta1)){
  res[i] <- i
  x <- interp$x
  your.number=theta1[[i]]
  num <- which(abs(x-your.number)==min(abs(x-your.number)))
  res[i] <- interp$y[[num]]
 }
return(res)
}

myfunction(df)
```

> [1] 0.00000000 0.09649999 0.06152762 0.12175866 0.91457862

However, my real data has several rows. Thus, I tried to use `apply` but I got an error:

```
apply(df,1,myfunction)
```

> Error in 1:numc : argument of length 0

Some idea to make it work?

Comment: Try `apply(df,1,ncol)`, then `apply(df,1,length)`.

Comment: also see `which.min`